# how to convert color value to exact precision using php

Tags: php, image-processing

i have values of color in rgba with this format RGBA(20,40,60,1) and i want to convert in real number with exact precision. how can i do this in php for example

```
Red 20 =  0.074510
Green 40 = 0.156863
Blue 60 = 0.231373
alpha 1 = 1.000000
```

Comment: What's the relationship between 20 and 0.074510?

Comment: How much precision do you need? `bcdiv("40","255",200)` goes to 200 after the decimal for instance. The answer seems to be `0,(15686274509803921568627450980392)`, infinitely repeated. So, what is _"exact"_?

Comment: I don't even know how you are getting those decimal values. As far as I can tell, 20 should be `0.078125`, 40 should be `0.15625` and 60 should be `0.234375`. This isn't even that hard of a calculation. There are 256 levels of each channel for rgb. So `20/256`. It is that simple. Closest I can get to your values, is in the range of 258-260 colors per channel. Also, if 20 is `0.074510` wouldn't it mean that a value of 40 is twice as large? And yet `0.074510 * 2 = 0.14902`.

Comment: @JonathanKuh: There are 256 values, of which 0 is one, so, divide by `255`. How would you ever reach `1` otherwise? 255/256 != 1. If the values ranged from 1-256, we'd still have the problem of not reaching 0 in a scale of 0 to 1. 256 values means 255 ranges 'between'  the numbers.

Comment: @Wrikken Thanks. I don't do a lot of base conversion like this so I always get confused about whether it is 255 or 256. Makes sense. Other problems still exist.

Comment: Using that scale and those decimal numbers, you get red=19, green=40 and blue=59.

Comment: Hah, you're right. The only one there that seems to be correct is the green one...

Answer (score -1):

```
function color2number($color) {
    $return = (1/250*$color);
    return $return
}
```

For alpha you need a special function or add a second parameter to the function for that :)

Comment: 250? That's a hell of a _"precision"_, and a somewhat roundabout way of writing `return $color/250;` (or `return $color/255;` if we want to be a bit more precise.

Comment: Haha yea 255 xD sry my bad. Was writing this on my iPhone. Hard enoigh :)